# Explain hex variable in the background.js of a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

What does the var _0x2596 mean? and It is a background.js. Why it's now working?

```
var _0x2596 = ['https://animoto.com/account','https://serpstat.com/grouping/index/*','https://animoto.com/account/sign_out','https://www.semrush.com/organic_traffic_insights*','https://moz.com/messages/*','isProxy','https://www.skillshare.com/perks*','https://www.skillshare.com/workshops*','https://help.skillshare.com/*','https://serpstat.com/','https://.linkedin.com/learning/settings*','semrush.com','get','https://www.picmonkey.com/home/account*','userFirstExtensionData','https://*.semrush.com/projects/*','https://learn.picmonkey.com/*','https://ahrefs.com','author','https://support.canva.com/*','onBeforeRequest','https://analytics.moz.com/pro/manage-campaigns','https://*.keywordtool.io/search-*']
```

Comment: `What does the var _0x2596 mean?` It's just a variable with an unusual name. It gets an array of strings assigned to it.  `Why it's now working?` I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Can I personally contact you? I need help

Comment: This is not a dating site ;). Feel free to ask questions or comment on questions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicholas Tower said, it's just a variable name.

And while [naming things](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) can be hard, the writer of this code used a nice trick by using the [Unicode Character 0x259F](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x2596/index.html).

So in this case, the variable name is ▖